# windows 8 library path error after deleting old user account folder

Tags: windows-error-reporting

My profile was corrupted,So I made a new user account and deleted my old one,it asked me to keep the files and said yes,after that it made a new folder on my desktop with stuff from my old user account and I went to see if I can access the library with pictures,music and videos,after I saw I could I deleted the folder of my old user account on my desktop and emptied the recycle bin now I get a path error and can't access any library,please help me

Answer (score 0):

Libraries are not real folders in any meaningful way. Instead, they are a *view* of a folder which exists somewhere on your hard drive, and their actual location can be changed arbitrarily, so that they can point to *any* folder. This makes them very powerful, and easily frustrating or confusing.

I cannot say for sure, but my guess is that the Library you accessed was pointing to the folder which you deleted. If that is true, the only way to recover it would be by un-deleting the files from the hard disk, using either a Tech Support company, or file recovery software. Either way, it's time consuming, and not guaranteed to work. (Sorry!)

The only true way to undo mistakes is to do regular backups to an external drive, or to a web service.